# Fixed header in web browser plug-in

Tags: css, google-chrome

My fixed header plug-in won't push down the webpage and just sits on top of the webpage. What am I missing?

```
.banner{
  position: fixed; 
  display: block; 
  top: 0px; 
  margin-top: 0px; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  background-color: #FFFFFF; 
  width: 1360px; 
  z-index: 50000;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to do a fixed topbar that doesn't overlap the top?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633352/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-fixed-topbar-that-doesnt-overlap-the-top)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always do this

```
margin-top:-1000px
```

1000px-just example

Comment: That's not fixing the problem of moving the webpage down.